# purpose of creating DEPENDENCIES_OUTPUT file while compiling c program

Tags: c, gcc, dependencies

gcc -MD file.c creates a dependency output file named file.d. But I dont understand the need of creating this file ( dependency file ), because when error comes while compilation, no dependency file is generated. So can anyone throw some light when he/she has used this dependency file or some usefulness of this file / feature of gcc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file.d file can be understand by [make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/make). You often first generate the .d files, include them into your Makefile and then compile the c-files only if one of the included headers has changed.

Don't bother about if you don't use make.

[GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) says:

> Instead of outputting the result of preprocessing, output a rule suitable for make describing the dependencies of the main source file. The preprocessor outputs one make rule containing the object file name for that source file, a colon, and the names of all the included files, including those coming from -include or -imacros command line options.

Comment: but i have not seen anyone who includes .d file in the makefile for file dependency check. Doesn't this increases the complexity of writing makefile ( first generate .d file for each and then include ?) Though usage looks good, probably make automatically does similar this to detect file change.